# Downloading a "Pending" document with tabs attached

Tags: docusignapi

Using the API, is there any way I can download a document that's still in a pending status with all of the tabs attached to it? The idea is that I'd like to be able to download an unsigned document with all of the text tabs filled in so that it can be printed out, but obviously it hasn't gone through the signing steps in Docusign.

My workflow is like this:

1. Create a new envelope from a template with a PDF document, filling in all the text tabs with the text I want in the PDF
2. Creating a signing URL for that envelope (but not visiting the URL)
3. Downloading the document in the envelope

The resulting document is just the template PDF with none of the tabs filled in. I've read that this is expected behavior since the document is still in the "sent" status, it hasn't been signed yet.

Is there anything that I can do such that in step #3, I download the pdf with tags attached to the document without having to visit the signing URL and manually completing the document? Is there something I can do with either the recipient's role or an API call that allows me to complete the document so that the tags are attached?

Comment: Why are you creating a signing URL if you don't use it?

Comment: @Ergin I don't need to, we have other documents where there is signing and it's all from the same workflow. For the documents related to this question, the URL isn't needed, we could skip that step.

Comment: Hmm it seem like an odd use case.  Well, DocuSign tabs are always with respect to a given recipient and are never assigned to the document itself.  With that said, you can easily grab the data in the tabs if you make the **Get Tab Information for a Recipient** call (check the REST API guide).  That should work whether the doc is completed or not.  Not sure if that helps accomplish you goal?

Comment: @Ergin No, I'm aware of the API call that fetches the values in the tabs, but the problem is that I already know what they are (I set them when I created the envelope). I really just need the PDF with the fields filled in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the current state of a PDF from DocuSign using our REST API. I would recommend the two account settings below. The documentation for a REST API GET of the PDF is available in the hyperlink below.

I just ran a test (signer1 entered data into text fields, checkbox, and signature applied), signer2 still pending. The downloaded PDF had the data for signer1 visible in the PDF. There is an 'in process' watermark on the PDF, but you can disable this via the account setting below.

**Enable watermark for in-process documents** = false

**Display SecureField initial value to all recipients** = true

[Retrieving Envelope and Documents](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Retrieving%20Envelope%20and%20Documents.htm)

Comment: Nice, the only thing I would add is that you might need to switch to the Classic (older) UI in your developer sandbox account to access these settings.  For those who don't know, DocuSign released a completely revamped UI not too long ago which is called NDSE (New DocuSign Experience).  By default developer sandbox accounts start out in NDSE, to access classic UI go to `Preferences` -> `Switch to Classic` and you'll have a lot more options available in your Preferences menu.